# Can't select specific paramter from eloquent relationship collection - works in tinker

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am attempting to get the latest user to have updated a document.

I have setup the database and relationships in the document model as follows:

```
public function getLastUpdateUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'created_by');
}
```

This function IS working in tinker.

I am passing the document data to a component and display it as follows:

```
<div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{ $doc->getLastUpdateUser}}
</div>
```

This shows me all the data for the user who last updated the document. However the problem is I cannot select a specific paramter from this collection. This code:

```
<div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{ $doc->getLastUpdateUser->name}}
</div>
```

Produces the following error:

```
Attempt to read property "name" on null
```

Despite the fact that I can see all the data including 'name' if i remove the ->name.

Hopefully I'm being really dense but I have been trying to work out why this is causing an issue for hours. It works perfectly in tinker. I also have the exact same relationships to other models which are all working in the same componenet.

Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Comment: try  $doc->getLastUpdateUser()->first()->name

Comment: You have getLastUpdateUser as a null. The relationship is not fetching any user from database. See the result from $doc->getLastUpdateUser

Comment: @OMR Weird -  'Call to undefined method App\Models\Privilege::getLastUpdateUser()' -> why would it be searching a model I haven't referenced ?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel as I said - I'm not getting null - getLastUpdateUser gives me all the user data but getLastUpdateUser->name results in null

Comment: @swift--help I am sure you are getting null. The error is specifying those

Comment: @RajeshPaudel - getLastUpdateUser - gives me all the user data on the page as intended - it is 100% not producing null. getLastUpdateUser->name then produces a null. This is why I am so confused.

Comment: Instead of {{ $doc->getLastUpdateUser->name}} use 
@if(is_null($doc->getLastUpdateUser)) 
{{ dd($doc) }} 
@endif 

and check the result. You might have some user with the null data then this happens in case you are iterating on collections and some have null data

Comment: @RajeshPaudel Thanks very much for all your help. I'd produced the error in a very silly way. Please see my answer for what I had done! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who lands on this post in the future.

This issue was a product of html abstraction.

I had abstracted a table into a component that I called multiple times on the page in question.

I had then supplied these table with their specific data sets and got to work making the first one work.

Unfortunatly this error was being produced by a table I hadn't started working on yet which was being supplied with a dataset whos model didnt have the getLatestUserUpdate model.

Every time the error was thrown I assumed it was an issue witch the bit of code I was activley working on.

Silly mistake.

Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your relation definition:

the second parameter in [hasOne](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) relation should be the foreign key, the relation should be:

```
public function getLastUpdateUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'created_by');
}
```

Comment: Hi OMR - id was the foreign key. I've actually worked out what was wrong - I'll post shortly. Thanks for all your help. Always the way that you work it out as soon as you post.